# sorting columns with in a row SQlite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a table like this

```
tbl1
    w1  w2  w3  w4   w5   w6
    4   6    2  17   29    3
```

I am trying to get output like this

```
new_C1   new_C2 new_C3    new_C4  New_C5  New_C6
 2         3    4            6      17     29
```

my piece of code is below but it isn't working with column 3 and 4

```
SELECT
MIN(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6) AS new_c1,
CASE MIN(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6) 
                         WHEN w1 THEN MIN(w2, w3, w4,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w2 THEN MIN(w1, w3, w4,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w3 THEN MIN(w1, w2, w4,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w4 THEN MIN(w1, w2, w3,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w5 THEN MIN(w1, w2, w3,w4,w6)
                         WHEN w6 THEN MIN(w1, w2, w3,w4,w5)
                         END AS new_c2,
CASE MIN(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6) 
                         WHEN w1 THEN MIN(w2, w3, w4,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w2 THEN MIN(w1, w3, w4,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w3 THEN MIN(w1, w2, w4,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w4 THEN MIN(w1, w2, w3,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w5 THEN MIN(w1, w2, w3,w4,w6)
                         WHEN w6 THEN MIN(w1, w2, w3,w4,w5)
                         END AS new_c3,

CASE MAX(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6) 
                         WHEN w1 THEN MAX(w2, w3, w4,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w2 THEN MAX(w1, w3, w4,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w3 THEN MAX(w1, w2, w4,w5,w6)
                         WHEN w4 THEN MAX(w1, w2, w3,w5,w6)
                         END AS new_c5,
MAX(w1, w2, w3, w4,w5,w6) AS newC6
FROM tb1
```

Can some one please help me with code in SQLlite ? especially for w3 and w4

Comment: This is nothing I would do in SQL. Your approach is not bad, but... For the second column you must know the result for the first, which is six possibilities you must consider. For the third column you must know the result for column #2 and hence consider 6x6 possibilities. For the third you'll write 6x6x6 lines... If you must do this in SQL, I'd suggest an iterative process, i.e. a recursive query. Or pivot the columns to rows with `UNION ALL`, then use `ROW_NUMBER` to get a sort key, then unpivot with conditional aggregation. As said: Nothing I'd do with SQL.

Comment: Maybe you just need another data model. If your database contained the values in rows instead of columns, you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use a lateral join(implemented using `cross apply`):

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then w end) as w1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then w end) as w2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then w end) as w3,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then w end) as w4,
             max(case when seqnum = 5 then w end) as w5,
             max(case when seqnum = 6 then w end) as w6
      from (select v.w, row_number() over (order by v.w) as seqnum
            from (values (w1), (w2), (w3), (w4), (w5), (w6)) v(w)
           ) v
     ) v
```

SQLite does not have similar functionality.

Comment: @forpas . . . READ the question.  The OP clearly states that the solution can be in either SQL Server to SQLite.  Apparently, you also removed the tag.